# orientdb produces java.lang.String cannot be cast on check database and repair database

Tags: orientdb

We just moved from distributed to non distributed, the configuration is similar minus the distributed selection, and now we are getting

java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.OIdentifiable only when we check database or repair database

I have researched previous questions and answers and do not see a similar match.  Please advise.

Comment: Ho BrianM what version are you using?

Comment: 2.2.28 is our version

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to do an export then an import from the console?

Comment: I have exported without problem but have not imported as of yet

Comment: Can you do an import and then run check database or repair database ?